# PHP - How to sum up elements from multiple arrays that share same keys

Tags: php

I have multiple arrays:

```
Array
(
    ['a'] => 5
    ['b'] => 5
    ['c'] => 5
)

Array
(
    ['a'] => 10
    ['b'] => 10
    ['c'] => 10
)

Array
(
    ['a'] => 15
    ['b'] => 15
    ['c'] => 15
)
...
```

Then I need to sum up the elements of those arrays for example `['a']` will be `5+10+15` ..

Then I have an array that has all the sum of those arrays

```
Array
(
    ['a'] => 30
    ['b'] => 30
    ['c'] => 30
)
```

Multiple arrays are taken from DB , is it possible to sum all the elements of the array during looping? Thanks

Comment: Group by in sql?

Comment: You will have to provide use with the actual query you're using to fetch from the db to make it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `array_map()` and `array_sum()`,

```
<?php
$a = array('a' => 5,'b' => 5,'c' => 5);
$b =array('a' => 10,'b' => 10,'c' => 10);
$c = array('a' => 15,'b' => 15,'c' => 15);
$d = array_map(function (...$arrays) {
    return array_sum($arrays);
}, $a, $b, $c);

print_r($d);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/pcURT

If you want to keep keys then try this way with simple `foreach()`,

```
foreach (array_keys($a + $b + $c) as $k) {
    $d[$k] = $a[$k] + $b[$k] + $c[$k];
}
print_r($d);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/IKKDK

Comment: Hi , is had missed out some in my question, the multiple arrays are taken from DB , is it possible to sum the arrays during `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead declaring them as `$a` `$b` `$c` ..

Comment: what is wrong with multiple array processing on php side, why you need it on mysql side?

Comment: If array element is not equal then what will be happened?

Comment: where OP mentioned that the array element may not be equal?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny sorry, i didnt get it clear enough , what i mean was , those arrays was taken from DB in serialized form , in PHP , it will unserialize all the arrays and get it into an array form , so during the loop , can I sum the elements , because the numbers of array might not be same everytime the script runs